# Concordancia entre sujeto y verbo en una frase subordinada

Tags: verbos

De estas dos frases, ¿cuál es la correcta?

> 1. Una de las más grandes profecías contenida en la Biblia.
> 2. Una de las más grandes profecías contenidas en la Biblia.

Personalmente, ambas me parecen correctas dependiendo de a qué se refiera cada una, pero dudo que realmente ambas sean correctas.

La 1 me parece correcta porque se habla de "una" y la 2 porque "dentro de las grandes profecias contenidas hay una".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesante pregunta. Ambas son correctas, pero tienen diferente significado.

**La primera** es correcta sólo si agregas las siguientes comas:

> Una de las más grandes profecías, contenida en la Biblia, habla de ...

y dice que la profecía a la que te refieres, está contenida en la biblia. Pero la *grandeza* está siendo comparada con todas las demás profecías (no sólo las que aparecen en la Biblia). El singular en *contenida* enfatiza que sólo consideras que esa *una*, tu sujeto, está contenida en la biblia. La frase 1 se entendería más o menos como sigue:

> Cierta profecía bíblica, una de las más grandes (¡de todas las religiones!), habla de...

**La segunda,**

> Una de las más grandes profecías contenidas en la Biblia habla de ...

constriñe todas las profecías, cuya grandeza está siendo comparada, a las de la Biblia. Excluye toda comparación que se salga de ese libro.